# Importing spark.implicits._ inside a Jupyter notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

In order to make use of `$"my_column"` constructs within a `spark sql` we need to:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

This is however not working afaict inside a `jupyter` notebook cell: the result is:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:49: error: stable identifier required, but this.$line7$read.spark.implicits found.
       import spark.implicits._
                    ^
```

I have seen notebooks in the past for which that *did* work - but they may have been `zeppelin`.. Is there a way to get this for `jupyter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack that works

```
val spark2: SparkSession = spark
import spark2.implicits._
```

So now the `spark2` reference is "stable" apparently.